# ui-router automatically changing root state url to abstract

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Some state routes were not working and when I started debugging my app using browser console I figured out that my root url is is defined as abstract.

Here are states.

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    data: {
        authorizedRoles: [appconfig.USER_ROLES.guest]
    }
})
.state('test', {
    url: '/testing',
    templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
    data: {
        authorizedRoles: [appconfig.USER_ROLES.guest]
    }
})
```

and at the end 
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');`

Here is the output I got in browser console.

```
$stateChangeStart from: Object { url="^", abstract=true, name="", more...}
$stateChangeStart to test- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : 

Object { url="/testing", templateUrl="views/test.html", data={...}, more...}
```

After this point nothing happens even no error. I have tested following events:

- `$stateChangeStart` ( working and nothing happens after this )
- `$stateChangeError`
- `$stateChangeSuccess`
- `$stateNotFound`

What possibly is wrong I am diong?

Answer (score 0):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZSs86lHiXfMm6NypTdD?p=preview). Your configuration should be working, just the `'home'` should have **template** or **templateUrl** defined as well:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    data: {
      authorizedRoles: [appconfig.USER_ROLES.guest]
    }
  })
  .state('test', {
      url: '/testing',
      templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
      data: {
        authorizedRoles: [appconfig.USER_ROLES.guest]
      }
  })
```

check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZSs86lHiXfMm6NypTdD?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have set a template for home and I saw that home state is completely not working. The template was not loaded.

Comment: Not sure if I do undrstand your comment. My plunker (with your stuff) is working. So is your solution working now as well?

Comment: Yes your plunker is working fine but I have some other problem, can't understand why this simple stuff is not working.